# Change PHP warning error into custom error image

Tags: php, customization, message

just wanna ask if it is possible that to change PHP warning error into image saying something went wrong and if its possible can you make a sample? thank you in advance :)

don;t know how to do it so i haven't yet try it

Comment: you can display whatever you want in the event of an error with some thought and configuration. With Apache it is easy to set custom error handlers within the config - so you can have entire pages dedicated to particular error types (ie: 404, 400 etc) and within PHP you can configure your error handling routines to display text or images or both

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can write a [custom error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). But warnings can happen in the middle of the script. There's no obvious way to display a picture in the browser in an unpredicted arbitrary place. You can of course detect if [output has been emitted](https://php.net/headers_sent) and act accordingly.

Comment: Here is a complete example: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#code